# Por qué se me pone la pantalla en gris apenas abro la aplicación android desde play store

Tags: android, flutter, dart, rest

***Buenas gente,***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*les cuento que esta es mi primera aplicación con FLUTTER,
el IDE que uso, es ANDROID STUDIO,
y lo que hace mi aplciación es usar un servicio REST para poder conectarse a una serie de datos de una URL en especifica,
la primera pantalla es el login, en verdad en mi emulador funciona bien, lo probé con mi celular fisico tambien, pero cuándo lo subí al play store, me salta una pantalla gris directamente,*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*en verdad no entiendo por qué, no tengo ningun error que me salte de la consola, quizas pienso que tiene que ver con la manera que armé los widgets,
les dejo la primera clase main*

```
        import 'dart:convert';

        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
        import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
        import "dart:async";
        import 'herramientas/menu.dart';
        import 'herramientas/variables_globales.dart';

        void main() {
          runApp( Login());
        }

        class Login extends StatefulWidget {

          @override
          _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
        }

        class _LoginState extends State<Login> {

          //creación de editText
          final usuario = TextEditingController();
          final password = TextEditingController();
          //creación de string donde se colocaran los edittext
          String usu = "";
          String pass ="";

          //string para guardar en el shared
          late String usuarioObtenido;
          late String passwordObtenido;

          Future<void >mostrar_datos()async{
            final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

            setState(() {
              usuario.text = ( prefs.getString("usuario"))!;
              password.text = ( prefs.getString("password"))!;
            });
          }
          //llamada del metodo mostrar
          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            mostrar_datos();
          }

          //la parte visual
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor :Colors.purple,
                  //titulo de la pantalla
                  title: Text("Orden de Compra"),
                ),
                drawer: Menu(),
                body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          final FocusScopeNode focus = FocusScope.of(context);
          //condicion si detecta un click afuera, enfoca la pantalla y saca el teclado
          if(!focus.hasPrimaryFocus && focus.hasFocus ){
            FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
          }
        },
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            //aca pongo la imagen e n este container
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50, horizontal: 50),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png"),
            ),
            //aca pongo el usuario
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child:  TextField(
                //ahora conecto con lo que quiero poner
                controller : usuario,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "usuario"
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //aca la conraseña
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child:  TextField(
                controller : password,
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "contraseña"
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //aca el boton
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.purple
                ),
                child: const Text(
                    "Ingresar",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontFamily: "bold"
                    )
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  //toma lo que agregaste y lo coloca en los strings
                  usu = usuario.text;
                  pass = password.text;

                  final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await 
                  SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                  sharedPreferences.setString("usuario", usu);
                  sharedPreferences.setString("password", pass);

                  var baseUrl = "http://quantumconsulting.servehttp.com:925";
                  late String api = "/jderest/v3/orchestrator/MQ0401P_ORCH";
                  //   Future<dynamic> post(String api, dynamic object) async {
                  var url = Uri.parse(baseUrl + api);
                  //var _payload = json.encode(object);

                  //transformo el usuario y contraseña en base 64
                  autorizacionGlobal = 'Basic '+base64Encode(utf8.encode('$usu:$pass'));
                  print(autorizacionGlobal);

                  var _headers = {
                    "Authorization" : autorizacionGlobal,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  };
                  var response = await http.post(url, headers: _headers);
                  print("este es el status " + response.statusCode.toString());
                  if (response.statusCode == 200) {

                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/bienvenida");

                    print("este es el status " + response.statusCode.toString());

                  }else if( response.statusCode  == 403   ){
                    showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context){
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: Text("Datos errorneos "),
                        content: SingleChildScrollView(
                          //es como un listView
                          child: ListBody(
                            children:[
                              Text ("verifica tus datos"),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        actions: [
                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text("aceptar"),
                            onPressed: (){
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text("cancelar"),
                            onPressed: (){
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    });
                  }else{
                    showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context){
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: Text("Error "),
                        content: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: ListBody(
                            children:[
                              Text ("verifica tus datos"),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        actions: [
                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text("aceptar"),
                            onPressed: (){
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text("cancelar"),
                            onPressed: (){
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    });
                  }

                  //para imprimir
                  //print(usu + pass);

                  //para blanquear
                  //para blanquear
                  //usuario.text = "";
                  //   };
                },
              ),
            )

          ],
        )
    )
);
```

}
}

corrí el comando `flutter run --release`

dando cómo resultado lo siguiente

```
I/flutter (10742): Null check operator used on a null value
I/flutter (10742): #0      Directionality.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart:179)
I/flutter (10742): #1      ScaffoldState.build (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:2736)
I/flutter (10742): #2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5066)
I/flutter (10742): #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4954)
I/flutter (10742): #4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5119)
I/flutter (10742): #5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4674)
I/flutter (10742): #6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4936)
I/flutter (10742): #7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5110)
I/flutter (10742): #8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4930)
I/flutter (10742): #9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3942)
I/flutter (10742): #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679)
I/flutter (10742): #11     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4979)
I/flutter (10742): #12     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5119)
I/flutter (10742): #13     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4674)
I/flutter (10742): #14     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4936)
I/flutter (10742): #15     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5110)
I/flutter (10742): #16     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4930)
I/flutter (10742): #17     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3942)
I/flutter (10742): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679)
I/flutter (10742): #19     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4979)
I/flutter (10742): #20     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4674)
I/flutter (10742): #21     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4936)
I/flutter (10742): #22     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4930)
I/flutter (10742): #23     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3942)
I/flutter (10742): #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679)
I/flutter (10742): #25     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4979)
I/flutter (10742): #26     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5119)
I/flutter (10742): #27     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4674)
I/flutter (10742): #28     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4936)
I/flutter (10742): #29     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5110)
I/flutter (10742): #30     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4930)
I/flutter (10742): #31     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3942)
I/flutter (10742): #32     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679)
I/flutter (10742): #33     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4979)
I/flutter (10742): #34     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4674)
I/flutter (10742): #35     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4936)
I/flutter (10742): #36     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4930)
I/flutter (10742): #37     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3942)
I/flutter (10742): #38     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679)
I/flutter (10742): #39     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4979)
I/flutter (10742): #40     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4674)
I/flutter (10742): #41     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4936)
I/flutter (10742): #42     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4930)
I/flutter (10742): #43     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3942)
I/flutter (10742): #44     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679)
I/flutter (10742): #45     RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1196)
I/flutter (10742): #46     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1165)
I/flutter (10742): #47     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1112)
I/flutter (10742): #48     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2691)
I/flutter (10742): #49     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1111)
I/flutter (10742): #50     WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:945)
I/flutter (10742): #51     WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:925)
I/flutter (10742): #55     _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192)
I/flutter (10742): (elided 3 frames from class _Timer and dart:async-patch)
E/flutter (10742): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (10742): #0      _MyAppState.mostrar_datos.<anonymous closure> (package:mq04f/main.dart:36)
E/flutter (10742): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1132)
E/flutter (10742): #2      _MyAppState.mostrar_datos             (package:mq04f/main.dart:35)
E/flutter (10742): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10742):
```

Comment: te servirá esto? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292922/pageview-display-grey-screen-when-in-release-mode/60293217#60293217

Comment: Quizá haya algo que está bloqueando el dibujado de la aplicación y por eso se ve gris. Si lo debugeas paso a paso no obtienes más información?

Comment: el que me pasaste agustin, lo habia encontrado antes de formular, pero no tengo el widget de EXPANDED, asi que lo descarte, pero me da una idea que tiene que ver justamente lo que dice Mateo, que hay algo que esta bloqueando, voy a ver si puedo darle mas atención al debugueo, aunque antes no me saltó nada

Comment: No se ve nada en la consola, pero revisaste el LogCat? Usas alguna API de mapas , firebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aquí podría ser que no tienes el permiso de internet en tu AndroidManifest ya el permiso de internet solo esta agregado por defecto en el AndroidManifest de la carpeta debug.

> agrego una imagen de referencia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También podrías revisar que puedes estar recibiendo un null al cargar las preferencias en tu función mostrar_datos.

En caso de que no sea lo que te indique, este tipo de errores los puedes detectar corriendo tu código con el comando:

```
flutter run --release
```

Ya que parece que tu app se esta rompiendo en el modo release pero en debug te va bastante bien, corre tu código con el comando que te indique arriba y y mira tu **debug console**

Comment: excelente, muchas gracias, justo estaba buscando la forma de lanzarlo en modo release, muchas gracias por tu comentario!

Comment: actualicé el post, corrí el comando  que sugeriste y me da lo siguiente

Comment: Agregue una nueva respuesta con una posible solución a tu error ya que tú log indica que estás recibiendo un null

Comment: muchas gracias por tu tiempo Jeovani, espero tu respuesta, me esta ayudando un montón

Comment: Para evitar ese error de null te sugiero editar tu función mostrar datos y dejarla algo así

    if(prefs.containsKey("usuario") || prefs.containsKey("password")){
          setState(() { 
            usuario.text = ( prefs.getString("usuario"))!; 
            password.text = ( prefs.getString("password"))!;
           }
    }